# Azure B2C Groups

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In Azure, if you edit a User you get a menu that allows them to be added to a Group.  However, I can see no blade that allows you to add, update or delete a Group.  What am I missing?  Is this one of those features that's only available through the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manage groups from Azure Active Directory blade, just not the Azure AD B2C blade. I don't have an explanation as to why (although I'm sure there is one).

[image]